# Why does "City of Blinding Lights" say that blessings go to both those who pray and those who steal?

Tags: song-lyrics, u2

The song *City of Blinding Lights* by U2 contains the following verse:

> In the city of blinding lights,
> The more you know
> The less you feel
> Some pray for, others steal
> Blessings not just for the ones who kneel, luckily

What does the last line refer to? Why do blessings go both to the ones who steal and the ones who pray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the author is alluding to the biblical principal of God's undeserved kindness.  If God doesn't bless problematic people, none of us could ever be blessed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Could you please cite a passage in the Bible where this principle is expressed?